# parental control

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire

I have a Kindle Fire and I have mistyped the password for the parental controls. I do not care how long it takes to reset the personal settings. all I want is for the thing not to be locked and not to lose anything. is there any way to do this with out losing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect with Technical Support of the software you use, or install another keylogger ( I use http://www.refog.com/ for all my Android gadgets). Last year I had the similar problem, I just installed another parental control software)Good luck!